# How to compute accuracy for CNN when outputs are one-hot encoded

Tags: neural-network

I want to compute accuracy of my model on test data. I have three classes so actual output might look like this :

```
[0 1 0]
```

and the predicted output might look like this:

```
[0.1 0.8 0.1]
```

How do I compute accuracy with this?
Shall I compute cross entropy and subtract 1 from that?

Answer (score 1):

Predicted class is the one with highest probability in output vector (class B in your case) & accuracy is correct predictions %, unless I'm missing your point.

The problem that you have mentioned is representative of multi-class classification which is solved using Softmax output layer in neutral net. NOTE that Softmax uses Cross Entropy as loss function.

I feel that calculating Cross Entropy on output may not make sense.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your problem, you have three classes, in the above example, which are one-hot encoded. For instance,

```
actual = [0 1 0]
pred = [0.1 0.8 0.1]
```

To find accuracy in such a case what you would do is get the index of the element with the maximum value in both the actual_labels and the pred_labels as:

```
act_label = numpy.argmax(actual) # act_label = 1 (index)
pred_label = numpy.argmax(pred) # pred_label = 1 (index)
```

Do this for every instance in the data, and increment number_of_correct_predictions whenever these indices match

```
correct = 0
total = 0
for i in range(len(data)):
    act_label = numpy.argmax(actual[i]) # act_label = 1 (index)
    pred_label = numpy.argmax(pred[i]) # pred_label = 1 (index)
    if(act_label == pred_label):
        correct += 1
    total += 1
accuracy = (correct/total)
```

Although this is a very basic method of getting the job done, there do exist more simplified versions of this spanning to just a few lines of code.

If you don't mind using libraries for this, you can use one in sklearn:

```
from sklearn.metrics import accuracy_score

accuracy = accuracy_score(y_true=actual, y_pred=pred) # Also gives the accuracy for the two lists actual and pred
```